# Jquery Image slider with data(images,title,description) being loaded from XML file

Tags: jquery, xml

I am trying to build a `jquery image slider` for my home page ,,,, i know there are unlimited `tutorials` for the same , but my requirement is that i want the `slider` to be independent ie i would like to have the `images,title,description` to be loaded from `XML file` ,,, so that in future i would just have to change `XML file`...Can anyone suggest me how to start with this as  i am fairly new to `XML`....
Thank you

Comment: There are plenty tutorials on parsing xml with jquery as well.

Comment: You could store the data as JSON and use Handlebars (http://handlebarsjs.com/) to build the markup from your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ajax to get XML and parse it.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/
http://think2loud.com/224-reading-xml-with-jquery/
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/xml-parsing-with-jquery

Find a slider you like or write your own.

http://naldzgraphics.net/tutorials/25-must-learn-slider-tutorials-with-jquery/

Use jQuery to buil the html portion of your slider from the parsed XML

http://api.jquery.com/append/